# vue-chartjs does not respond correctly to data changes

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3

Did everything as indicated on the [official vue-charts website](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts). I need the graph itself to track the changes of labels, data1, data2, which will increase and be redrawn. I click on the Add button, new entries are added on the x axis, but the addition of the y axis is not displayed and this error occurs in the browser console.

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:220 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at pauseTracking (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:247:1)
    at instrumentations.<computed> (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:441:1)
    at Proxy.value (helpers.collection.ts?1493:138:1)
    at instrumentations.<computed> (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:442:1)
    at Proxy.value (helpers.collection.ts?1493:138:1)
    at instrumentations.<computed> (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:442:1)
    at Proxy.value (helpers.collection.ts?1493:138:1)
    at instrumentations.<computed> (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:442:1)
    at Proxy.value (helpers.collection.ts?1493:138:1)
    at instrumentations.<computed> (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:442:1)
```

Dependencies in the package.json file:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "chart.js": "^4.0.1",
  "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^1.2.1",
  "core-js": "^3.8.3",
  "vue": "^3.2.13",
  "vue-chartjs": "^4.1.2"
}
```

This is how the component looks like:

```html
<template>
  <div @click="addRecord">Add</div>
  <Line :chart-data="getData" :chart-options="getOptions"/>
</template>

<script>
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs';
import zoomPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-zoom';

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  zoomPlugin
);

export default {
  name: "LineChart",
  components: {Line},
  data() {
    return {
      labels: [],
      data1: [],
      data2: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addRecord() {
      const last_v = this.labels.length ? this.labels[this.labels.length - 1] : 0;
      this.labels.push(last_v + 1);
      this.data1.push(4);
      this.data2.push(5);
    }
  },
  computed: {
      getOptions() {
          return {
              label: 'Load',
              borderWidth: 2,
              animation: false,
              spanGaps: false,
              maintainAspectRatio: false,
              interaction: {
                  intersect: false,
                  mode: 'index'
              },
              pointRadius: 0,
              scales: {
                  x: {
                      ticks: {
                          source: 'auto',
                          // Disabled rotation for performance
                          // maxRotation: 0,
                          autoSkip: true,
                      }
                  }
              },
              responsive: true,
              plugins: {
                  tooltip: {
                      callbacks: {
                          label: function(context) {
                              return `${context.raw} мм.`;
                          }
                      }
                  },
                  title: {
                      display: true,
                      text: 'x'
                  },
                  zoom: {
                      pan: {
                          enabled: true,
                          mode: 'x'
                      },
                      limits: {
                          x: {min: 50}
                      },
                      zoom: {
                          mode: 'x',
                          wheel: {
                              enabled: true,
                          }
                      }
                  }
              },
          }
      },
    getData() {
      return {
        labels: this.labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Axis x',
            borderColor: 'red',
            data: this.data1
          },
          {
            label: 'Axis z',
            borderColor: 'green',
            data: this.data2
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is quite a lot of questions regarding that on stackoverflow already. Did you gave it a search?

Comment: Also, be sure that the v4 is compatible: https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/940